# Hub sites navigation links to respect the site permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, site, hub-site

We have multiple layers of Hub Sites, and we are using those options to show the related child Hubs and the related Hubs:-

[image]

but seems the links will be shown regardless if the login user have permission to view the related site or not. So can we force the Hub sites navigation links to respect the site permissions? similar to how the usual site links works? where the link will not be shown unless the login user have read permission on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely the short answer to this case is NO